# Loading Images from Web Api in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: image, azure, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage

I need to load a picture from a web api backend into my Xamarin.Forms app.
The picture is stored in an Azure Blob Storage.

This is my Web Api method:

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("ConnectionString");

    // Create the blob client.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("picturecontainer");

    // Retrieve reference to a blob named "photo.jpg".
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("picture");

    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(stream);

    Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    HttpResponseMessage result = new    HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());

    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

    return result;
}
```

In my app I try to download the image bytes with the following code:

```cs
public App ()
{
    _client = new HttpClient();
    _client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;

    Button downloadImageBtn = new Button () {
        Text = "Download Image",
    };
    var image = new Image() {
        Source = ImageSource.FromUri (new Uri ("http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg")),
        Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit
    };
    downloadImageBtn.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        var values = await handleClick (sender, e);
        uploadPicButton.Text = values;
        var imageBytes = await downloadPicture();
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
    };

    MainPage = new ContentPage {
        Content = new StackLayout {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children = {
                image,
                downloadImageBtn
            }
        }
    };
}

private async Task<byte[]> downloadPicture()
{
    var uri = new Uri (string.Format (RestUrl, "5"));
    //return await _client.GetByteArrayAsync (uri);
    var response = await _client.GetAsync (uri);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync ();
        return content;
    }
    throw new HttpRequestException ();
}
```

However when I click on the button, the placeholder image disappears.
Is there a problem when sending the image from the server or when receiving it in the app?

Comment: You don't show the code of downloadPicture, so I don't know whether the problem is inside this function. Try to debug. Put a breakpoint after you get imageBytes. How many bytes are there? Is it null or empty by any chance? Does it correspond to your picture's size?

Comment: @Grisha I added the `downloadPicture()` code to the questions. However, when the picture is send from the server the content body has arround 170k bytes, but there are only 265 returned image bytes.

Comment: Ok,  we are closer. Now check on server side, in Get function, how many bytes do you send. Check result.Content.

Comment: @Grisha Like I said in the previous comment, the size of the `result.Content` int the `Get` function is about 170k bytes

Answer (score 1):

I'd not implement downloading Images manually.

If you want to load more images and/or allow to display a placeholder while loading, I recommend the [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading) library. It offers nice functionality like downloading, caching, showing placeholder and error images and most important: down sampling the image to the target size. This is always a pain on android. Its available for native UI xamarin projects and for Xamarin.Froms.

You can bind strings that contain urls directly to the Source. The code would like like:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage 
    Source="http://thecatapi.com/?id=MTQ5MzcyNA">
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

Answer (score 0):

After blockblob.DownloadToStream line, try to set Position of the stream to 0. I'm not familiar with Azure API, but I think it may help.

Also ,try to use `ReadAsStreamAsync` instead of `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` in your `downloadPicture` function. Something like this:

```
var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
byte[] buf = new byte[512];
int bufSize;
while((bufSize = (await responseStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length))) > 0)
{
    // store the received bytes to some buffer until the file is fully downloaded
}
```

Do you get all your content this way?